# Constantly visible notification and access icon for Empathy in Gnome 3

Tags: gnome3, empathy

Since a short while I'm using Ubuntu Oneiric Ocelot (11.10) with gnome-shell (Gnome 3) and I'm trying to get accustomed to the default Empathy Instant Messaging client.

One mayor problem for me (coming from Gnome 2 and Psi) is that there is no constantly visible icon which makes it clear (for example by changing its icon or showing an animation) if there are incoming messages which I did not read already and which lets me jump into them with one click.

Also I'm missing a way to bring up the contact list or hide it away with a click. I sometimes have real problems even figuring out how to even open the contact list up again.

Is there a Gnome 3 extension or some other trick available to display such a notifier in the top bar? I'm talking about something just like the sound and network controls which are already located there.

I know that there are notifications in the lower notification area (former system tray), but as it is only visible as I move the mouse in the lower right corner of the screen, its useless for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this incredibly long bug report](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=641723) for discussion about persistent notification of unread messages that doesn't require you to scrub the bottom corner all the time.

Answer (score 2):

This extension worked for me http://www.webupd8.org/2011/11/never-miss-im-notifications-in-gnome.html

Comment: Can be installed from here: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/150/message-notifier/